# How would I automate dropping a column in R based on summary data for that column?

Tags: r, tidyverse, summary

I have a dataset that is being used to create an automated dashboard. Essentially it's looking at the relationship between certain conditions and the cost of care on a month by month basis for a health care institution. What I want to be able to do is in pseudocode:

```
dataset %>% select(-c("columns where the average value is lower than X"))
```

No amount of googling seems to be getting me close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `select_if`

```
library(dplyr)
val <- 10
dataset %>%
    select_if(~ is.numeric(.) && mean(.) < val)
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
dataset[, names(which(colMeans(dataset[sapply(dataset, class) == 
            "numeric"]) < val)), drop = FALSE]
#   col3
#1    3
#2    4
#3    7
```

#### data

```
dataset <- data.frame(col1 = c('A', 'B', 'C'), col2 = c(10, 8, 15),
     col3 = c(3, 4, 7), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks a million.